# SQL regex replace for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to cleanup some text. To achieve that, I came up with following query

```
Select message,
Case
when REGEXP_Count(message, 'Refreshing|update|create', 1, 'i') > 0 then REGEXP_REPLACE(message, 'Refreshing|Update|create', 'Edited',1, 1, 'i')
when REGEXP_Count(message, 'Open|View', 1, 'i') > 0 then REGEXP_REPLACE(message, 'Open|View', 'Viewed',1, 1, 'i')
else message 
end
From audit_log al
```

Is there a better way to handle such replacement so I do not have to repeat REGEXP function twice? I'll need to handle approx 50 different replacements

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace each value:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(message, 'Refreshing|Update|create', 'Edited',1, 1, 'i'
                             ), 'Open|View', 'Viewed', 1, 1, 'i'
              )
```

This is not 100% equivalent.  But assuming that the message has only one of the strings, it should do what you want,.

Answer (score 0):

With 50 or more of these mappings, it seems to me that you have crossed a threshold and you need a different kind of solution to help you manage and maintain this better.

Why don't you create a simple mapping table with two columns, action and actionclass, then populate it with ('refreshing','edited'), ('update','edited'), etc.

If there are more than one of these keywords in a message then both this solution and your solution behave strangely.  This solution returns two instances of the same record with different keywords replaced, while your solution ignores the match of the second keyword entirely.

```
Select message, Regexp_Replace(message, m.action, m.actiontype,1,1,'i') as newmsg
From audit_log, Actions m
Where instr(message, m.action)> 0
```

Comment: It has to be one query as I am not able to create any mapping tables. On the other hand this is just a one off job, so really not a problem when it comes to maintaining the list.